# Apple push notifications only working on one device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have push notifications working on my main development device... but it is not working for my test device (using the same application).  Does the test device also need to be set up as a development device?  The app works.. it just does not populate the device token up to the server.  I need to be able to send the app to testers and have push notifications work for everyone.

Comment: How are you testing an app on a device that isn't provisioned for development in the first place?

Comment: the app is built with the distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: But the device is still registered in the dev portal yes?

Comment: yeah.  The app works fine.  it's just that the notifications do not work for that device.  the token is not sent to the server.  I am going to try and get a hold of the device and debug locally.. I am just wondering if the regular distribution profile does not allow for notifications in the dev sandbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware that an app built with a development provision profile, must be notified trough the sandbox-version of the PNS-service with a development push certificate. If your application is built with a distribution sertificate ( either ad hoc or App store), you must use the production PNS-service with a production push certificate.

Hope this helps:)